# How do you specify <requirements> in the manifest?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm deeply frustrated and hoping someone can help.

My Word Add-in requires 1.1, and (as a newbie) I've found the MS documentation and submission process ambiguous/confusing. They take 2 days, then reject my Add-in.

To their credit, they include a lot of detail and have found legit issues.

The only item standing in my way is calling out 1.1 in the manifest, so Word 2013 users can't even see it.

The example code they give doesn't work in my Manifest when I submit it. Here's the sample they provide at https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements.

```
<Requirements>
 <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
   <Set Name="TableBindings" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   <Set Name="OOXML" MinVersion="1.1"/>
 </Sets>
 <Methods>
    <Method Name="Document.getSelectedDataAsync"/>
 </Methods>
</Requirements>
```

I submitted the following, ***which was accepted by their XML checker and ran fine in Word Online*** and they bounced me. I hadn't checked using an installed Word (my bad) because I've found Word Online to be the gold standard:

```
<Requirements>
  <Methods>
    <Method Name="Document.insertText"/>
  </Methods>
</Requirements>
```

They bounced the manifest with these lines (the rest of the manifest is fine and has been checked multiple times)...

All I want to do is block Word 2013. That's it.

I've been trying variations and loading in Word 2016 for Mac and can't get it to work. I know that the manifest is sequencing-sensitive...meaning if you put something in the wrong place it won't work. I've got  right after .

I'm really hoping to avoid waiting another 3 days to get feedback on a typo.

Help deeply appreciated while I continue to experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your requirements node should look like this:

```js
 <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

Comment: OH MY LORD...thank you Juan.

I was thrown WAY off by this example from Microsoft: [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/overview/add-in-manifests.md) (scroll down to the "Outlook add-in manifest v1.1. example")...it uses "Mailbox" instead of "OutlookApi" or similar...
  `<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>`

This solution works and now I know to include "WordApi" I see other discussions about it...

Comment: Thanks, is really not obvious and i searched for a long time, then i started taking all office-js threads on stackoverflow one by one and jackpot :)